# Adding Multiple Arguments into an built in function, from a function

Tags: javascript, arguments, fromcharcode

I'm trying to add String.fromCharCode(). And adding it into a function that renames it like so:

```
function from() {
    var ar = arguments.length;
    var argumentss = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < ar; i++) {
        var a = argumentss + '\'' + arguments[i];
           if (i == ar - 1) {
               argumentss = a + '\''
           } else {
               argumentss = a + '\', '
           }
    }
    var arg = eval(argumentss);
    return String.fromCharCode(arg)
}
```

I need to do this, so don't say that there is no reason to do this, since the way im actually using it there is a reason.

What im trying to do is make it possible to do:

```
from(65,66,67) //returns ABC
```

Without doing `function from(a,b,c)`

Since with the fromCharCode you can do as many arguments as you want. It would also be useful if there was a custom fromCharCode function. Thanks

Comment: I might miss the point, but you can assign any variable a function. `var from = String.fromCharCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
function from() {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       result += String.fromCharCode(arguments[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

from(65,66,67)
//result ->  ABC
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, I didn't think of that at all(:

Answer (score 0):

Does this address your problem? Call this once at the beginning:

```
String.from = String.fromCharCode.bind(String)
```

and use later:

```
String.from(65, 66, 67)  //"ABC"
```

Using built-in [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).